# Running a node.js script on multiple servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, ssh, server

I have a node.js script that I currently execute on 7 separate servers. Right now what I have done is copy the script to all 7 servers and execute them individually.

This works but I have to make frequent modifications to the source code which in turn would mean I have to re-do the above every time there is a change which is extremely tedious.

So my question is how can I make this process simpler? I have ssh access to all 7 servers.

Comment: Look into system admin tools like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather broad question, but I'll give you a basic run-through.

There are a number of tools and approaches which can be used to keep multiple servers in sync.

There are tools like `rsync` which are used to synchronize files between systems. Using this, you would make the change on one, and then it would get replicated to others. Note that it wouldn't restart your app, so you'd need some kind of trigger (like `nodemon`) to watch for changes and do that.

There are also tools that let you SSH and control multiple boxes simultaneously, like `pssh`. Here is a topic on this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers

There are tools that help automate deploy pipelines. `Fabric` is one such tool (as mentioned by Timo in the comments).

Finally, and perhaps the cleanest method, is to use some kind of continuous deployment system like GitLab or TeamCity, where you can have a build pipeline that triggers when you make a commit and will roll out for you. This is the approach most professionals take.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution(with some security risk) as I did this some days ago.

### on master server

target file `index.js` should be placed.

### On other server

load that `js` file (try axios) then `eval` that script.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const url = 'full_url';


axios.get(url)
  .then((file) => {
    eval(file.data);
  });
```